# How to stop Android Studio 4.0 from downloading latest sdk

Tags: android, android-studio

I just got the latest version of Android Studio 4.0 and when I create a new project it automatically downloads the Android SDK Platform 29.

I disabled updating in the settings and it still downloads that SDK.

Is there any way to disable it, or do I have to revert back to Android Studio 3.6.3?

Comment: "when I create a new project it automatically downloads the Android SDK Platform 29" -- the newly-created project has `compileSdkVersion 29`, most likely. "do I have to revert back to Android Studio 3.6.3" -- you should have the same results. I just created a new project in AS 3.6.3 in the new-project wizard, choosing the "Empty Activity" template, Kotlin language, and `minSdkVersion 21`. The resulting project had `compileSdkVersion 29`, and if I did not have that SDK installed, Android Studio would need to download it.

Comment: Android Studio 3.6.3 uses compileSdkVersion 28, targetSdkVersion 28 and buildToolsVersion "29.0.3 if that's what I have installed. I doesn't automatically download the latest version.